# Database relationship between two databases

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to create a little blog system. Under each article should be a comment function. I think, I need 2 Databases (1x for the normal articles, 1x for the comments of ech article). Now I dont now how i can create a relationship between boths databases. Here is a picture:

[image: Picture]

On this picture are the attributes of each database. And how can i contact the databases then? (write & read)

Comment: This is not html nor css. Also, a "table" is not a database. You should look at basic table relationship through foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make for every type you want a table. i.e one for articles, writers, categorys etc.

```
Table articles
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+
| id | writer_id | title |    date    | message | category_id |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |     12    | foo   | 2015-01-26 | text    |      34     |
|  2 |     12    | bar   | 2015-01-27 | bar     |      32     |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+

table writer and so on

+-----------+------+
| writer_id | name |
+-----------+------+
|    12     | test |
+-----------+------+

Table comments

+------------+------------+---------+------+
| comment_id | article_id | comment | date |
+------------+------------+---------+------+
```

and so on

afterwards you can connect them in your sql

```
SELECT
 `articles`.`title`,
 `writer`.`name`,
 `comments`.`comment`
FROM
 `articles`
 LEFT JOIN `writer` ON (`writer`.`writer_id` = `articles`.`writer_id`)
 LEFT JOIN `comments` ON (`comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`)
```

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins for a visual explanation of joins.

Answer (score 1):

You need two tables in the same database and you can connect them with a foreign key.

ARTICLE (ID_ARTICLE,WRITER,TITLE,DATE,MESSAGE....)

COMMENT (ID_COMMENT,FK_ARTICLE(to know the article), COMMENT_WRITER ...  )